# webbrowser control memory usage high

Tags: windows-phone-8, browser

I have a question about system memory.
I have integrated a web browser within my application.  Surfing the web, the memory usage grows up more and more.. apparently it’s windows phone that manages memory during pages browsing (at least for the browser), so i should not have any memory exception. The problem happens when I leave the view on the browser: my memory usage remains HIGH. I’m talking about 50-60MB or 90/95 MB (on some site). I’ve tried to perform a memory clean on exit without any success… if i use the app in this way I certainly will fall into a memory exception because the memory usage never goes down

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        await Browser.ClearInternetCacheAsync();
        await Browser.ClearCookiesAsync();

        ContentPanel.Children.Remove(Browser);

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Does anyone has a solution to this problem?
Please let me know

Comment: will you be able to use WebBrowserTask?

Comment: No. I need to use the browser in my application

Answer (score 0):

You do copy the code from OnNavigatedFrom to OnNavigatingFrom and at various stages of app like while surfing only,not at last stage i.e. OnNavigatedFrom ,as this is issue with that control only.
also try calling `await new WebBrowser().ClearCookiesAsync()` before and after every web browser session.