# Is network download will affect java script functioning in web browser control in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, browser

I am working on a book reader windows phone 8 application. Where `Web browser` control is used for loading my saved html file.

We are generating the `html file` after downloading the file from the server by using `Background transfer service` for that.

But After 2 or more download process when i try to load html by the web browser , the functionality became delayed. And this delay never happening on the session where we are not downloading the file from the network.

Is there some factor in the download process affects the Web browser from working ? Can any one have any information about this?

Answer (score 0):

When working with javascript in the web browser control you should always make sure java script is enabled. This may solve your problem.

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="BrowserControl1" IsScriptEnabled="True" />
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing the memory?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815880/webbrowser-control-memory-usage-high

Comment: I used to load html pages saved in local folder. So do i need to clear cookies? The problem occurs on both high and low memory

Comment: I would try one by one and see if clearing has any affect on the performance.

Comment: I checked it. But no difference at all.